# C++ How to access private static variable in another class

Tags: c++, variables, static, private, member

I am trying to access a private static variable (*PhysicsEngine::**_world**->setDebugDrawer(&debugDraw);*) from another class.

First class:

```
namespace GameEngine
{
    class PhysicsEngine
    {
    private:
        // Pointer to Bullet's World simulation
        static btDynamicsWorld* _world;
```

Second class:

```
bool Game::initialise()
    {
        _device = irr::createDevice(irr::video::EDT_OPENGL,
                                    _dimensions,
                                    16,
                                    false,
                                    false,
                                    false,
                                    &inputHandler);

        if(!_device)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error creating device" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        _device->setWindowCaption(_caption.c_str());

    //////////////
    DebugDraw debugDraw(game._device);
    debugDraw.setDebugMode(
    btIDebugDraw::DBG_DrawWireframe |
    btIDebugDraw::DBG_DrawAabb |
    btIDebugDraw::DBG_DrawContactPoints |
    //btIDebugDraw::DBG_DrawText |
    //btIDebugDraw::DBG_DrawConstraintLimits |
    btIDebugDraw::DBG_DrawConstraints //|
    );
    PhysicsEngine::_world->setDebugDrawer(&debugDraw);
```

If I make _world public I get Unhandled exception at 0x00EC6910 in Bullet01.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: if you wanna reach it from outside why not make it public then?

Comment: Sounds like you need some `friend`s

Comment: @CaptainObvlious or proper design

Comment: You don't get exception because of variable access type...

Comment: Instead write a public method in `PhysicsEngine` that takes `debugDraw` and would call the `setDebugDrawer` on _world and set the `debugDraw`.

Comment: The exception may have something to do with `setDebugDrawer` implementation. How is it implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose some static function in the Physics Engine class which returns a reference or pointer to the private static variable _world then call that static function.

```
PhysicsEngine::getWorld()->setDebugDrawer(&debugDraw);
```

Expose the below method

```
static btDynamicsWorld* getWorld() { return _world; }
```

Comment: Thank you that worked... however I still get the access violation. I probably should look more into Bullet Physics.

Comment: What access violation do you get? Did you put the above method under public access?

Comment: I realised my stupidity and placed it into Private, I thought worked but I just don't get the access violation. Now I get error C2248: 'GameEngine::PhysicsEngine::getWorld' : cannot access private member declared in class 'GameEngine::PhysicsEngine'

Answer (score 0):

Declare that class as  Friend in this class. Then the member functions of that class can access this private static member.